# Flask app works locally, fails on heroku. Procfile and requirements.txt didn't do it..?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, tesseract

Started going a bit mad on this, hence first post.
I have yet to deploy an app public facing for others to use. They launch locally just fine..
How can I get this app to deploy on Heroku?

Here is my repository: https://github.com/codereyes-1/tesseract_flask_new

I wrote a python app in Flask that makes a call to google tesseract function. The app works locally but fails in Heroku.

There is no Flask build pack I can find. Some research returned "add a requirements.txt and Profile" but that didn't work.
Here is the build log from Heroku:

"
Building on the Heroku-20 stack

-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python

-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz

```
   More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
```

!     Push failed
"

¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Comment: This is usually when requirements.txt is missing, did you push it to Heroku? Maybe trying adding here the full log of the Heroku build

Comment: "Started going a bit mad on this" -- my deepest sympathies to a fellow sufferer. Have you tried running `heroku local`? It gives more debugging info than opening the app online. If not, at which point are you getting the error?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65888631/how-do-i-use-heroku-postgres-with-my-flask-sqlalchemy-app/66708153#66708153) might help

Comment: @BeppeC I did push .txt but no luck

Comment: @Still_learning thank you sir, this is looking like a pointer in the right direction. Got some stuff to do on this now. I'll update with my findings!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you will need to do to deploy your app to Heroku:

1. Login to heroku on your terminal (`$ heroku login`)
2. Ensure your application is in a `git` repository (`$ git remote -v`)
3. Create a Heroku application (`$ heroku apps:create my_app-app`)
4. Create `Postgres` database (`$ heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`)
5. Log errors to `STDOUT`
6. Set environment variables in Heroku (`$ heroku config:set LOG_TO_STDOUT=1 # Add  others if you have them`)
7. Install `gunicorn` and `psycopg2` (`$ pip3 install gunicorn psycopg2`)
8. Add `Procfile` to root directory and update it (`$ touch Procfile`)
9. Update your `requirements.txt` (`pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`)
10. Commit your changes (`$ git commit -m '<your-commit-message>'`)
11. A remote Heroku repository (`$ heroku git:remote -a <your-heroku-app-name>`)
12. Push to Heroku (`$ git push heroku master`)

Comment: Hey Gitau, thanks for this. I'll be able to work on this tomorrow night, hope to get it running.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing "web: gunicorn app:app" in my Procfile, I matched python to supported versions in runtime.txt.App launches correctly with these settings.

@BeppeC @Still_learning @Gitau Harrison Thank you all for your help. I got the app deployed, and I learned how to deploy my other apps as well.