# flask app database data is automatically removed after some time which is deployed in heroku

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, heroku

I created an SQLite database in the flask and when I tested the website I submitted some data and it work fine but when I deployed the app in Heroku and tested it again [heroku app](https://my-top.herokuapp.com/) by adding some data it stored it and worked properly so I closed that tab. but when I revisited the site after 1 hr the data that I added after deploying the app in Heroku is not there. it happens all the time

MY database code

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///categories.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'anime': 'sqlite:///anime.db',
    'movie': 'sqlite:///movies.db'
}
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
Bootstrap(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# CREATE TABLE
class Categories(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    review = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
db.create_all()


class Anime(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'anime'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    year = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    rating = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    ranking = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    review = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
db.create_all()


class Movie(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = "movie"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    year = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    rating = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    ranking = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    review = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
db.create_all()
```

website :-[Click Hear](https://my-top.herokuapp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Dynos use an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Sqlite is not a reliable database to use in this environment because it is stored as a file on the local filesystem and will be destroyed regularly in the application's lifetime.

In this environment, I would recommend using a hosted database solution such as [Heroku Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres).

**Edit 2021-10-18**: I stumbled up official Heroku documentation about [SQLite on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3). As far as connecting SQLAlchemy to Postgres, I found an extremely thorough StackOverflow Answer to the question [How do I use Heroku Postgres with my flask-sqlalchemy app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66708153/147333).

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get it. Can you explain to me properly how to use it?

Comment: @AnkurRawat I made an update with more information on SQLite in Heroku and a very thorough StackOverflow answer that walks step-by-step through setting up Heroku Postgres with a flask app.